# Formatting HTTP request with Alamofire "format=json&body="

Tags: swift, httprequest, alamofire

I'm trying to send an api request that needs to look like this:

https://api.gibbly.com/1/device?format=json&body={"selection"={"selectionType":"registered","selectionMatch":"","includeRuntime":true}}

However, when I use the code below, I get an error.  In the [RESULT] segment of the response, I get the following:

```
[RESULT] FAILURE: responseSerializationFailed(reason: Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}))
```

I've tried the request using Postman and it works fine so I think the issue is caused by the code.

Based on the first "print" statement in the code, the HTTP body seems correct:

```
Optional({"selection":{"selectionType":"registered","selectionMatch":"","includeSettings":true}})
```

The only thing I can think of is that Alamofire isn't adding "format=json&body=" into the request but I can't figure out how to see whether that's the case.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
        let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
            "Authorization": "Bearer adsf023494axadf32342",
            "Content-Type": "text/json"
        ]

        let parameters: [String: Any] = [
            "selection":[
                "selectionType":"registered",
                "selectionMatch":"",
                "includeSettings":true
            ]
        ]

        Alamofire.request(url!, method: .get, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON {
            response in
print(NSString(data: (response.request?.httpBody)!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue))
            print(response)
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure thats the API format ? It looks like you are sending data meant to be in a HTTP body as part of query string

Comment: Try with content-type `application/json` if you are sending parameters in GET request, if not use `URLEncoding.default` as encoding.

Answer (score 0):

For GET method use URLEncoding.default instead of JSONEncoding.default in Alamofire request

Comment: Thanks.  I tried that and got a serialization error.  Any other thoughts?  SUCCESS: {
    status =     {
        code = 4;
        message = "Serialization error. Request contains no body. Ensure body is provided and POST Content-Type specified correctly.";
    };
}

Comment: that is because, on respsnse, you are trying to print request body like this,
print(NSString(data: (response.request?.httpBody)!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue))
But there is no request body in your request since it is a GET request

Answer (score 0):

Ok figured it out.  I did the following: (1) created the parameters as a string, (2) percent encoded them so all the characters can be used as a url, (3) added the encoded parameters to the base url, and (4) used the new url with the base url and then encoded parameters as the url for my request.

```
let url = "https://api.gibbly.com/1/device?format=json&body="
        let urlParams = "{\"selection\":{\"selectionType\":\"registered\",\"selectionMatch\":\"\",\"includeSettings\":true}}"
        let urlEncoded = url + urlParams.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)!

        let headerList : HTTPHeaders = [
            "Authorization" : "Bearer " + (KeychainWrapper.standard.string(forKey: "accessToken"))!, 
            "Content-Type" : "text/json"
        ]

        Alamofire.request(urlEncoded, method: .get, headers: headerList).responseJSON{
            response in
print(response)
}
```